# what is the relationship between MSAcess and MSExcel?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm a MySQL user. I've never used either MSAccess or MSExcel, though Excel got installed the other day as part of MSOffice.

A customer asks me to incorporate MSAccess in his project. Is Excel an upgrade from Access? Or are they totally diff products? I see that I can download Access, but is it even supported anymore?

Cust gave me his database as a .mdb file, which Excel seems to know nothing about.

What's my next step in getting this database file running on my XP machine?

Thanks, everybody!

**EDIT:** I had downloaded a trial copy of MSOffice 2010 Home, which includes Excel but does not include Access. To get Access I downloaded a 60-day trial of  [**MSOffice 2010 Professional**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/get-microsoft-access-FX102159812.aspx?WT.mc_id=ODC_ENUS_OATAccessHome_MonTry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two completely different products.

Access is a database management application, with .mdb being the file based database structure.

Excel is a spreadsheet program. And although people tend to use it as a database and as a word processor too, it really isn't.

In Access it is possible to link to external tables, as if they were tables in the database. Access allows linking to various other database formats, but also supports Excel spreadsheets. That may be the source of your confusion.

Note that Access isn't server based. Access is critisized a lot because it doesn't scale so well. It is however a good and easy database to start with, and is very usable for small companies that just have a couple of PC's in a workgroup and not a complete server.

Access can be used in a multi-user fashion, but the 'regular' way of use is single user. Lots of people who do Access development try to have multiple single user connections to a database, which is really asking for trouble. 
Instead, you can create workgroups inside your Access database and use it in a true multi-user approach. 
Even though, I'd be reluctant to use Access in a multi-user environment, especially when you get to 5 users or more writing to the database. For read-only access, having more simultaneuous users isn't a problem at all.

Access itself does cost money, but that is the database management tool. The drivers are free, and you can create a database programmatically using only free tools, or you can use a single license to contruct the database and modify it from numerous PC's that don't have Access itself, but do have the free drivers.

Comment: @GolezTol -- thanks, that clears it up perfectly for me.

Comment: new for Access 2010 is web based development. The web system is based on Microsoft's new cloud os and thus can scale out to millions of users and the only REAL limit on number of users is the size of Microsoft's data center – and that is one big huge massive of a whale of a data center. So you effective have no limits on the number of users anymore.

Comment: Access is a development tool that lets you build applications that CONNECT to a database. So if you have a database in MySql or Oracle, then you need something for the business code, the forms, the reports etc. and the user interface. That is what Access allows you to build.

So no one would call VB6 or vb.net from Visual Studio 2010 "a database". One should thus no more do so to call Access a database. Access is an IDE to build applications with.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal And Microsoft Access has its own database format. So it's both the backand and the frontend, although they do not need to be used together. But I thought I made this distinction clear in my answer. In this case, the OP's client wants to incorporate his access database, in the form of an .mdb file, into his project, so it's quite obvious it's about the Access backend, and not about using the front end to manage an Oracle database.

Comment: I was also talking about the file based backend when I mentioned the limited users. The Microsoft Data centers will use SQL server, which can indeed scale to very large proportions. The management tools used do not matter, they do not determine those limits. But thanks for mentioning the web interface. It's worth knowing.

Comment: Access or Word or Excel file formats was not the issue. The distinction here is that a database engine called JET (not Access) reads that data. A file format is not the same thing as a database engine. Access is a developer tool that creates the interface to a database engine that you "choose". (that mdb might be connected to external data source).  You can use source code control for team development with Access and again in this context Access is not a database. This is not a big deal but a good distinction between Access and database engines is important even for file based applications.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is a spreadsheet, Access is a desktop relational database. Both are part of MS Office. .mdb is the file extension for a Access database (pre Office 2007 which introduced .accdb), you will need Access to view the file. Excel files have a .xls extension (or .xlsx for 2007 plus).

As an aside you will be able to connect to the file via Excel to view the data if required (look under the data tab).

Comment: thanks, that explains everything. Thanks especially for the aside.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an ODBC driver that will allow you to make a connection to an MS Access database.  Then you can establish a connection and import the data into MySQL.

But if you need the data in a native Excel spreadsheet, you will need to have Excel installed on your machine.